# Wrong Number of Arguments Used With Function in Query Expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, ms-access-2010

I have an SQL in Access 2010 that was written by someone else that gives a Wrong Number of Arguments error when I try and run it. It's supposed to filter a report from a search page.

```
    SELECT Activity.[ProjNo], Activity.[Code], Activity.[Type], Activity.[ProjNoStatus], 
           Activity.[Preliminary], Activity.[Planner], Activity.[Designer],  
           Activity.[Officer], Activity.[Manager], Activity.[Staff], Activity.[Analyst], 
           Activity.[Manager], Activity.[DeptHead], Activity.[ContractNumber], 
           Activity.[InfoOfficer],Activity.[ProjNoDesigner]
    FROM Activity
    WHERE Activity.ProjNo=Index.ProjNo AND (((IIf([Forms]![SearchForm]![txtCode]="",
          "*",[Activity].[Code]=[Forms]![SearchForm]![txtCode]))<>False) 
          AND ((IIf([Forms]![SearchForm]![txtType]="","*",[Activity].[ Type]="", 
          "*", [Activity].[Type]=[Forms]![SearchForm]![txtType]))<>False) AND 
          ((IIf([Forms]![SearchForm]![txtProjNoStatus]="","*",
          [Activity].[ProjNoStatus]<=[Forms]![SearchForm]![txtProjNoStatus]))<>False));
```

I'm not very experienced with SQL and, like I said, I didn't write this code (the person who did has long since retired) so any help would be great.

Comment: Please explain what you want those `IIf` expressions to do.

Comment: The IIf statements should see if the user selected a value and bring up the projects with that value, otherwise show all of them. I'm not sure what the `<>False` is for, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query defines just one data source (table or query):

```sql
FROM Activity
```

But then the `WHERE` clause appears to reference another data source named *Index*:

```sql
WHERE Activity.ProjNo=Index.ProjNo
```

Since *Index* is not included in the `FROM` clause, Access will object when you try to use it in the `WHERE` clause.

However, I'm not sure that is the cause of the first error Access complains about.  It may help to show us the full text of that error message.

Comment: That is the full comment. After that, it just shows the entire code.

Comment: Please test this as a new query in the Access query designer: `SELECT * FROM Activity WHERE Activity.ProjNo=Index.ProjNo`  Does that simpler query trigger an error?  If so, is it the same error you first reported in the question?

Comment: This doesn't give me any error.

Comment: Then when you run that query, does Access ask you to supply a value for `Index.ProjNo`?

Comment: Yes, it asks me for `Index.ProjNo`.

Comment: Good.  What happens if you remove `Activity.ProjNo=Index.ProjNo AND` from the original query?  Is there an error ... same or different than before?

Comment: It gives me the same error.

Comment: OK.  Do you have any reason to keep `Activity.ProjNo=Index.ProjNo AND` in the query?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is. But removing it still gives that same error.

Comment: Understood.  I needed to verify `Index.ProjNo` was a useless distraction from the "real" problem you're trying to solve.  Are you running Access with an interface language other than English?

Comment: As far as I know, it's only English.

Comment: "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression '`(((IIf([Forms]![SearchForm]![txtCode]="","*",[Activity].[ Code]=[Forms]![SearchForm]![txtCode]))<>False) AND ((IIf([Forms]![SearchForm]![txtType]="","*",[Activity].[ Type]="", "*",[Activity].[ Type]=[Forms]![SearchForm]![txtType]))<>False) AND ((IIf([Forms]![SearchForm]![txtProjNoStatus]="","*",[Activity].[ProjNoStatus]<=[Forms]![SearchForm]![txtProjNoStatus]))<>False));`."

Comment: This seems much like the situation you resolved in your previous question by using a pattern similar to: `some_field = text_box OR text_box Is Null`.  I think you should use that approach again here instead of those `IIf` expressions.